# Perfect image of a metrizable space is metrizable.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, paracompactness, metrizability

How can I prove that the perfect image of a metrizable space is metrizable?
I know the following three theorems about equivalent conditions of metrizability.

> A space $X$ is metrizable if and only if it is regular and has a basis that is countably locally finite.

> A space $X$ is metrizable if and only if it is regular and has a basis that is countably locally discrete.

> A space $X$ is metrizable if and only if it is a paracompact Hausdorff space that is locally metrizable.

Also I know that Hausdorffness, regularity, local compactness, second-countability, and paracompactness is preserved by perfect maps. How can I prove that metrizability is preserved by a perfect map using these facts(or +@ if needed)?

Comment: A proof is given in Engelking's book on page 284. The only things you need to understand it are the Nagata-Smirnov metrisation theorem (which you've quoted above), and that paracompactness is an invariant of perfect mappings.

Comment: @Tyrone: In my copy of Engelking it’s Theorem $4.4.15$ on page $355$.